# Trying to understand XML parsing error (caused by MS Word)

Tags: xml, ms-word

My colleague was writing a word document that keeps getting corrupted with an error that says 'the XML data is invalid according to the schema' or similar. I've looked at the document.xml file in Notepad++ and validated it, and it gives the error `XML Parsing error at line 316366: Premature end of data in tag document line 2`. Here is line 2:

```
 <w:document> xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"   
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

Here is line 316366:

```
</w:document>
```

That is the end of the document. What is wrong here? It looks to me as the tag is closed off ok.

Comment: Are you sure the `>` comes right after `w:document` on line 2?

Comment: That's not normally going to happen with MS Word.  You may have encountered a serious bug, but more likely your document has been edited incorrectly either manually or programmatically.

Comment: Quite possibly @kjhughes. I'm not actually working on it though so I am unable to diagnose anything there. But at least I can warn colleagues it is probably for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 2 should have been

```
<w:document
    xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"   
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
```

i.e. move the `>` to the very end.

Comment: I see, thanks. I think this must be a weird Word bug as i get exactly the same error code (in NP++) on a different - but still corrupt - document, but this one has the tag in the correct place as you stated.

Comment: @RichPrag: Then there are multiple errors.  Feel free to ask a new question, but choroba has addressed the only error presented in *this* question, so please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) his answer.  Thanks.